# Approach to sample 'C' challenge

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I was recently asked a theoretical C question and I was wondering what the best way to approach it would be:

If I had a document with 10 words on it what would be the best way to determine if there were duplicate words and if there were duplicates how would I keep track of how many there were?

Any insight on how you would approach this would be great.

Comment: if this is a homework you should tag it as #homework, is it?

Comment: no I was actually asked it on a job interview a couple of days ago and was never given the answer...I don't even need someone to write out the code was just interested on how they would do it...what data structure etc etc..

Comment: Get it sorted! Then it is easy to just count the duplicates up.

Comment: Fun question - would turn into a bunch of other add-ons as you went.  "What about 100 words?  1,000,000,000 words?  What's the big O complexity of your solutions and could you do it better?"  Stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretical interview questions like this always deal in small numbers (like 10 words). However, the number means nothing; it's there to separate out those candidates who really can think around the problem in *the general form* from those who simply regurgitate fixed answers to fixed interview questions they find on the internet.

The best software houses will only favour solutions that are **scalable**. Therefore, you will gain top marks in an interview if your answer is simple, but also scalable to any size of problem (or, in this case, document). Therefore, sorting, loops inside loops, O(n^2) complexity, forget them all. If you presented any solutions like these to a leading-edge software company at interview you would fail.

Your particular question is checking to see if you know about **Hash Tables**. The most efficient solution to this problem can be written in pseudo-code as follows:

```
1. Initialise a new hash table.
   For each word in the document...
2.     Generate a hash key for the word.
3.     Lookup the word in the hash table using the key. If it is found,
4.         Increment the count for the word.
       Otherwise,
5.         Store the new word in table and set its count to one.
```

The **most important benefit** of the above solution is that **only a single scan of the document is required**. No reading words into memory and then processing (two scans), no loops in loops (many scans), no sorting (even more passes). After exactly one pass of the document, if you read out the keys in the hash table, the count of each word tells you exactly how many times each word appeared in the document. Any word with a count greater than one is a duplicate.

The secret to this solution is its use of hash tables. Generation of the hash key (step 2), key lookup (step 3), and key storage (step 5) can be implemented as near *constant-time* operations. This means the time these steps take hardly changes as the size of the input set (i.e. number of words) grows. It means that whether it's the 10th word in a document, or the 10 millionth word, inserting that word into the hash table (or looking it up) will take roughly the same *very small* amount of time. In this case, we additionally keep a count of each word's frequency in step 5. Incrementing a value is known to be a very efficient fixed-time operation.

Any solution to this problem must scan all words in the document at least once. As our solution processes each word *exactly* once, with all words taking approximately the same very small *constant time* to process, we say our solution performs *optimally* and scales *linearly*, yielding *O(n) performance* (put simply, processing 1,000,000 words will take around 1000 times longer than processing 1000 words). In all, a scalable and efficient solution to the problem

Comment: Generating a hash key for a string is not constant time unless you are using a very poor hashing algorithm that doesn't look at the whole string.

Comment: @Jeremy P: As stated, I said they can be implemented in _near_ constant time. Of course, I assume that you know the meaning of "constant time" in the _asymptotic_ sense. As the maximum length of a word in this case is bounded, and in the general case can be considered small compared to the length of the document, any algorithm operating on a single word to generate a hash will operate in "constant time" when considered against the running time of the entire algorithm.

Comment: Is the maximum length of a "word" bounded?  I don't see anything in the specification as set out in the question that says that.  It does, on the other hand, limit the number of words to 10 for which it would be overkill to *write* a hash table (although not if you already have an implementation prewritten).

Comment: @JeremyP The whole point of interview questions is to confirm if the candidate is thinking about the problem and **how** they are thinking about the problem. The specification is intentionally vague to force the candidate to define the parameters to their solution. It doesn't say the maximum length of a word is bounded in the question; **I stated it** as a parameter to the solution that I proposed. I suggest that if you have a solution that's better than mine then share it so that I and the OP can benefit from your wisdom. That's what's Stack Overflow's for.

Comment: I agree, but if I was the interviewee, the first question I would ask is "does this need to be extensible to cases with more than 10 words?"  The reason being that, in commercial software development, you don't get paid for features that haven't been asked for.  Your solution makes assumptions, namely that the words are relatively short strings and that there will be a requirement.  While these assumptions may be perfectly legitimate, in an interview situation I would expect the candidate to at least discuss them.

Answer (score 5):

The keyword is "ten": this means that the simplest approach with two nested loops checking each word against each other in front of it will do just fine. If the number was, say, 10000000, an approach with hash tables, heaps, or sorted arrays would be warranted. With only ten words, however, you do not need to build anything complex - just the basic C string read/compare knowledge would be required.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://ideone.com/jiE1i) with a very simple implementation on ideone.

Answer (score 0):

1. read the words into array of strings, using scanf
2. for each word, compare to others later in the list, using strncmp

There are speed and space optimizations, but I (usually) optimize for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

For a larger implementation you can use a hash table and check collisions

For a small n (ex. n = 10), we can go through the elements and add them to an array. For each element check the array to see if it is a duplicate.

Checking the array is in O(n) and going through each of the 10 elements is in O(n). Since we can implement this simply with a nested loop, we can perform this in O(n^2) time complexity. This is sufficient because with such a small n value, performance impacts would be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the length of the individual words is likely "small", I would begin with a radix sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort which takes O(nk) time, where k is the maximum word length. In this case you would definitely want to first sort the words into separate lists according to length (up to n of them).

Because you're interested only in duplicates you can throw out any list (in this step or any subsequent step) of length 1.

For each list, compare the last character of each list member, creating a new list of words for each distinct character seen (up to 26 of them, assuming the words are all ASCII characters), truncating the last character. Again, throw out lists of length 1 and recursively sort the new list(s).

In the worst case (all words are the same length and differ only in the first character, assuming LSD radix sort) you'll get O(nk) time. In the best case (all words have different length) you'll get O(n) time. In real-world cases you'll probably get significantly better than O(nk) time so the solution should scale up well to longer word lists.